How to evaluate camel simple expression from varaible/header/property
I have a simple expression inside the varaible and want to evaluate this expression.
So, I have something like this: variable.Filter = ${jsonpath($.id)} == 1
I want to evaluate the expression inside this varaible. But when I evaluate simple(${variable.Filter}), I get the result ${jsonpath($.id)} == 1. I want the true or false result. How can I do this?
P.S. I use yaml-dsl

Did you already try a nested simple, like simple(simple(${variable.Filter}))?
